# Platform as a Service recommendation for fully automated DevOps infrastructure

Tags: automation, web-server

I have a Wordpress-like web app, in that every user needs their own dedicated server to run it. This gives them their own database, disk space, and CPU, plus they can use their own custom domain.

The service should configure everything (including containers, the software stack, SSL, routing for zero-downtime app updates, etc), handle server lifecycles, monitor their health, handle rollbacks, and so on... basically, a fully automated IT/DevOps infrastructure.

There needs to be a dashboard UI that I can use to manually do all these things, but also have an API so that I can provision servers dynamically whenever a user wants to create/upgrade/cancel their own server (using a UI I'm providing).

Does something like this exist?

- I know about **Heroku** and and it handles although it can host multiple apps that point to the same git repo, I can't do things like partial deploys (slow roll-out) to a random subset of instances. On top of that, I'm looking for a dashboard UI that will help orchestrate and manage a large number of these app instances, not just see a list of them with no overview of their health.
- There's **Nanobox.io** which is the closest thing I've found so far, but I can't get an answer from their sales team and their company in general seems like it's going to fold at any moment (their recent Glassdoor reviews are not good).

Are there any PaaS that fulfill my requirements that is reliable?

Comment: @Izzy Sorry, thanks for letting me know. I've changed my question to be more clear. I'm looking for an automated software platform that handles IT infrastructure. Is this the wrong place to ask?

Comment: Thin ice between web-app and hosting (this site is about recommending software – hosting requests are off-topic here). But I'll let the community decide. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jelastic Multi-Cloud DevOps PaaS](https://jelastic.com) covers all the described needs and requirements. There is a short video overview of the [main functionality and platform UI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8TYOx2NjvQ).

Jelastic is a cloud agnostic solution. The platform is available as a:

- public cloud with modern "pay-as-you-use" pricing at wide [network of independent cloud service providers](https://jelastic.cloud/) worldwide;
- private cloud on top AWS, Google, Azure, DigitalOcean or on top of own bare metal infrastructure;
- [hybrid or multi-cloud for enterprises](https://jelastic.com/enterprise-paas/#multi-cloud) that consolidates resources from different data centers and enhances security due to granular quotas and users/groups/regions access management.

Integrated [WordPress Enterprise](https://jelastic.com/wordpress-enterprise-services/) services simplify running farm of WordPress clusters for different customers. It provides high availability and geo-distributed load balancing, premium and lightning fast CDN, Let's Encrypt SSL auto renewal, high performance optimization for different topologies and stacks (standalone or cluster, LiteSpeed or NGINX, MariaDB or MySQL) and many more.

As a bonus, support of [Kubernetes Hosting](https://jelastic.com/kubernetes-hosting/) offers pre-configured Kubernetes clusters available just in a few clicks. The clusters are designed for automatic vertical and horizontal scaling with auto-discovery of new worker nodes as well as for cost savings with more efficient resource utilization and [pay-as-you-use pricing model](https://jelastic.com/public-cloud-pricing/).